# Can I convert a non-MVC asp.net application to be Azure compatible?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure

Can I convert a non-MVC asp.net application to be Azure compatible ? Or If i want to create an Azure web application, should it be MVC one ?

Comment: Azure is not restricted to ASP.NET apps.  You can use non-ASP.NET apps, regular web sites, ASP.NET (non-MVC), or ASP.NET MVC (any version).  Your choice of web app technology should not depend on the platform (Azure) but on your app's needs.

Answer (score 2):

The other answers answered your question about converting your app to MVC for deployment to Azure (you don't need to).

If you're creating a new web application and go with ASP.NET MVC (which I'd recommend), just remember if you go with MVC3, you may have to make some of the MVC3 DLL's CopyLocal for your deployment, as it won't be part of your web role instance.  At least that's how I still understand it.  The 1.4 SDK of the Azure SDK doesn't have a MVC3 Web Role template yet.

See this [post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/avkashchauhan/archive/2011/05/14/asp-net-mvc3-web-role-deployment-in-windows-azure-sdk-1-4-0-detailed-steps-and-full-sample-code.aspx) on steps to get your MVC3 app Azure-ready.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You may take a look at the [following blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jnak/archive/2010/02/08/migrating-an-existing-asp-net-app-to-run-on-windows-azure.aspx) for migrating an existing ASP.NET application to Azure. It should not necessarily be an ASP.NET MVC application. Any ASP.NET application will work.

Comment: In the post you linked to NerdDinner IS MVC !

Comment: @SIMSIM, ASP.NET MVC is an ASP.NET application.

Answer (score 0):

azure has 2 roles 
1. a webrole 
2. worker role

web role is nothing but an asp.net app. so no need to convert it into an MVC app just any asp.net thing will do fine

Comment: A web role is not an asp.net app. A web role is a Windows Server 2008 SP2 or R2 Virtual Machine, which is running IIS. You may choose to develop whatever you want on that web role, which might not even involve a web application (e.g. host a WCF service, or maybe a Java app listening on a port).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. But you need to be aware of certain limitations too, none of which were mentioned in the answers already given:

1. **Your application should be stateless**, unless you are running a single instance (for most apps 99,9% reliability is OK, but there are some where you want 99,95%, so you need at least two instances + it gives you additional benefits of a load balancer, etc.). The reason for this is that if you have more than one instance, the load balancer will deliver the request to a different instance. You can use [AppFabric Cache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff383731.aspx) to solve this.
2. **You don't have a file system** - this is not entirely true, but in reality you should never rely on having local files. All you image uploads (e.g. user profile pictures) should be uploaded to a blob storage and linked to there. How you do this is another matter, and one that can be approached differently depending on the architecture of your existing application. You can get away with files, by using Azure Drive, but it's slow as hell.
3. **No Event Log / RDP** - this is also only partially true, but you should rely on other ways of getting diagnostics information from your role. While you can RDP to your role instance, there are better ways (e.g. Azure Diagnostics storage).
4. **Database** should be chosen carefully. Sure, you have SQL Azure available, but it's *expensive* (1 GB = 10 USD/ month). If you can get away with stuff like Table Storage, you may save on some costs. Again, this depends a lot on the architecture.

As for the second part of your answer. MVC as a pattern is nice. It saves you a lot of time, it's much more adapt for the Web as WebForms ever will be. The event based system was designed for Desktop applications, and it was forced onto the web. However, going to Azure does not imply a requirement to go to MVC. What I suggest you do however, is treat it as a nice jump-start opportunity to look into MVC and see how it could help you write your apps better & faster.

As with any other case involving architecture of apps, **it depends**. If you used common patterns (e.g. IOC, Repository), you will have a really easy time moving any app to Azure.

Comment: "Can I convert a non-MVC asp.net application to be Azure compatible?" You didn't answer this part...